# Erro na criação de função em Python 3.7.0

Tags: python

Não consigo executar esse código, ele deve receber uma imagem em formato `.BMP` e retornar a lista de pixels, não sei o que pode estar errado:

```
from struct import pack
from struct import unpack

def ReadBMP(pach):

    image_file = open ('C:/img2.bmp', "rb" ,pach)

    image_file.seek(18)
    width = unpack('i', image_file.read(4))[0]
    height = unpack('i', image_file.read(4))[0]
    #print(width, height)
    image_file.seek(0,0)
    image_file.seek(54)

    rows = []
    row = []
    pixel_index = 0

    while True:
        if pixel_index == width:
            pixel_index = 0
            rows.insert(0, row)
            row = []
        pixel_index += 1

        r_string = image_file.read(1)
        g_string = image_file.read(1)
        b_string = image_file.read(1)

        if len(r_string) == 0:
            if len(rows) != height:
                print("Warning!!! Read to the end of the file at the correct sub-pixel (red) but we've not read 1080 rows!")
            break

        if len(g_string) == 0:
            print ("Warning!!! Got 0 length string for green. Breaking.")
            break

        if len(b_string) == 0:
            print ("Warning!!! Got 0 length string for blue. Breaking.")
            break

        r = ord(r_string)
        g = ord(g_string)
        b = ord(b_string)

        pixels = []
        pixels.append(b)
        pixels.append(g)
        pixels.append(r)
        row.append(pixels)
        #row.append(g)
        #row.append(r)

    image_file.close()

    return rows
```

Essa é a mensagem de erro:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    ReadBMP(pach)
NameError: name 'pach' is not defined
```

Comment: Como chamou a função? Qual é o valor de `pach`?

Comment: a função deveria ter o mesmo nome do arquivo (img2.bmp), porém o def ( ) não aceita o ponto, tentei colocar pach com um nome em comum mais não deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Ao definir uma função, colocamos no parênteses o nome de variáveis que irão receber os parâmetros passados para sua execução. Por exemplo, uma função que recebe o nome de um arquivo e o abre, seria assim:

```
def ler_arquivo(nome_arquivo):
    with open(nome_arquivo, 'rb') as arquivo:
         #... codigo aqui para trabalhar o arquivo ../
```

Somente na hora de chamar a função acima você deve passar um nome de arquivo, por exemplo:

```
ler_arquivo(r'c:\img2.bmp')
```

Ou então, outro exemplo, pedir ao usuário para digitar o parâmetro, e armazená-lo em uma variável, para depois passar para a função:

```
texto_digitado = input('Digite um nome de arquivo'):
ler_arquivo(texto_digitado)
```

No seu exemplo, pelo erro, você está tentando chamar a função, mas está tentando passar `pach`... Esse é o nome que você deu para a variável que receberá o parâmetro dentro da função, porém, ela não existe fora da função.

Um outro problema que vejo com o código é que o parâmetro declarado não está sendo usado dentro da função; O nome do arquivo está fixo no código da função... Se a função recebe um parâmetro, ele deveria ser usado; Caso contrário, a função executa sempre da mesma forma independente do parâmetro, logo não faz sentido ele existir.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!